# Java algorithm to track parts of aggregated values

Tags: java, algorithm, aggregate

My program have evaluate hundreds of millions of records. So the question of memory and performance are important.
Lets each record has key - ticketID. Also record has field value and field source_name.
In source ticketID have from 1 to many (neary 100) source_name.
I need aggregate only by ticketID - receive nearly 1 million of record, but also must have possibility subtract values for specified source_name - so I have track contributes.

Do exist some algorithms or data structures that allow resolve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of heavy lifting one lets a DB do....

Comment: Why don't you suggest an algorithm and discuss which methods are critical to improve for speed?  There's no such thing as an algorithm that doesn't trade off something for something else, and from your description, only a vague notion of the problem exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite parse the question fully so I'll assume:

- "nearly 1 million of record" means that there is nearly 1 million unique `ticketID` fields.
- "nearly 100" different `source_name`s in the system.
- not all `ticketId`s have `source_name`s.  We don't have 100 million `ticketID` x `source_name` combinations.
- You want to be able to total all of the `ticketId`s but also total by `source_name`.

With these assumptions I would use a `Map` of maps.  The outer `Map` has a key of `source_name` and the value of the inner `Map`.  The inner `Map` has a key of the `ticketId` and a cumulative `value`.

So the pseudo code would look something like:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer,Double>> valueMap =
    new HashMap<String, Map<Integer,Double>>();

while (...reading in and processing data...) {
    int ticketId = ...;
    String sourceName = ...;
    double entryValue = ...;

    Map<Integer,Double> sourceNameMap = valueMap.get(sourceName);
    Double value = sourceNameMap.get(ticketId);
    if (oldValue == null) {
        value = entryValue;
    } else {
        value += entryValue;
    }
    sourceNameMap.put(ticketId, value);
}
```

You can easily get the total by adding up each of the `source_name` maps.  You can also keep a running total for each `source_name` of course if that helps.  If your system can allocate a gigabyte to the JVM then it should be able to handle a good number of `ticketID` x `source_name` pairs.

You might consider creating a mutable internal value class to save on GC cycles:

```
private static class MutableValue {
    double value;
    public MutableValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public void add(double value) {
        this.value += value;
    }
}
```

So then you can say:

```
MutableValue value = sourceNameMap.get(ticketId);
if (oldValue == null) {
    sourceNameMap.put(new MutableValue(entryValue));
} else {
    value.add(entryValue);
}
```

If you edit your question, I'll edit my answer in case I've made some improper assumptions.