# HashMap group by (Java)

Tags: java, hashmap

Is there a way we can group by Key and add the value in a HashMap in Java

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    map.put("A", 2);
    map.put("A", 3);
    map.put("B", 4);
    map.put("A", 5);
    map.put("B", 4);
```

The result is

```
   A = 10
   B = 8
```

Any help would be helpful !!!

Comment: While doing put check element exists if it does then add and put.

Comment: Please explain what you want for the output instead.

Comment: yes, use an if statement and the `map.containsKey` method. you can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write utility method that does this:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
.........
public void putAndIncrement(String key, int value) {
    Integer prev = map.get(key);
    Integer newValue = value;
    if (prev != null) {
        newValue += prev.intValue();
    }
    map.put(newValue);
}
```

Comment: what if you want access all the values, may be next time for multiplication

Comment: @KaipaMSarma Then your solution is better.  However, that does not appear to be the OP's question.

Comment: @ZachLangley Question actually is focused on how to group the values based on a key. What i felt is when we group it, the solution should be retaining all the values so that any operations on the values can be supported.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
public void incrementValue(HashMap<String, Integer> map, String key, int value) {
    Integer old = map.get(key);
    if (old == null) {
        map.put(key, value);
    } else {
        map.put(key, value + old);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use a hashmap.

```
map.put("A", 2);
map.put("A", 3);
```

The second put overwrites the first put. Use a list. Loop through it and do the addition yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can group in this way

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>
```

Whenever you see `A` keep adding the values into its ArrayList

Comment: This takes O(n) time to retrieve the sum.

Answer (score 0):

See answer on [Java algorithm to track parts of aggregated values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7653041/926620):

```
private static class MutableValue {
    double value;
    public MutableValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public void add(double value) {
        this.value += value;
    }
}

MutableValue value = sourceNameMap.get(ticketId);
if (oldValue == null) {
    sourceNameMap.put(new MutableValue(entryValue));
} else {
    value.add(entryValue);
}
```