# Aggregate list of maps by id field

Tags: java

I am running an SQL statement that returns a collections of maps as follows:

```
    ["person_id" : "1", "eventid" :"1"]
    ["person_id" : "1", "eventid" :"2"]
    ["person_id" : "1", "eventid" :"3"]
    ["person_id" : "2", "eventid" :"1"]
    ["person_id" : "2", "eventid" :"2"]
    ["person_id" : "2", "eventid" :"3"]
```

What is the best way to convert them to the following hierarchy of maps:

```
["person_id" : "1", ["eventid" :"1", "eventid" :"2", "eventid" :"3"]]
["person_id" : "2", ["eventid" :"1", "eventid" :"2", "eventid" :"3"]]
```

Showing the one-to many relationship

Note that this query can return 100,000 records.

Comment: You mean "best way" in regards of time, resources, code legibility or what exactly?

Comment: Maybe this answer could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/12991149/3281415

Answer (score 0):

Use Collections:

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> partners=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    public void store(String partner, String id){
        ArrayList<String> ids=partners.get(partner);
        if (id==null){
            partners.put(partner, ids=new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        ids.add(id);
    }
    public void main(ResultSet input) throws SQLException{
        while(input.next()){
            store(input.getString(1),input.getString(2));
        }
    }
```